# Magento 2 checkout index xml is not overriding

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml

I am creating Magento 2 theme using the blank theme as the base. Now the problem is Magento 2 blank theme removing the top header, search bar, mini cart on http://www.yourdomain/checkout  page

`vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Checkout\layoutcheckout_cart_index.xml`

they have removed using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

If I override the same theme with here it is not working. What I want is not remove those elements so I have to override XML file here

`app\design\frontend\NAMESPACE\themename\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false"/>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

I have written `remove="false"` to not to remove those elements from checkout.

But it is still remove theme an idea ?

I have checked after clear cache and re-indexing but not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To override a layout XML file (rather than extend) you need to add it to a slightly different directory, more info can be found in [the official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html)

```
<theme_dir>
  |__/<Namespace_Module>
    |__/layout
      |__/override
         |__/theme
            |__/<Parent_Vendor>
               |__/<parent_theme>
                  |--<layout1>.xml
                  |--<layout2>.xml
```

So for your case where you need to override Magento\Blank it would be:

```
app\design\frontend\NAMESPACE\themename\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\blank\checkout_index_index.xml
```

If overriding the theme doesn't work, make sure you don't need to override the layout coming from the module itself rather than the theme's XML. To do this read the 'Override base layouts' section in the docs linked above.

Comment: already marked as correct ans...

Comment: What to do if I receive the following message:
_Overriding view file ... does not match to any of the files._ ?

Comment: It was set like this on version 2.06, but after upgrade to 2.1 I got this message. Moving file to 'layout' folder worked.

Comment: @VasiliiBurlacu - I haven't had chance to try with 2.1, but according to the docs the method of overriding XML files is the same on 2.1 - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: @Ben-Space48 I didn't say that overriding method changed, I wrote about the error I was given. My `checkout_index_index.ml` was in right there where your post says, but after upgrading to 2.1 and running `setup:upgrade` & `setup:static-content:deploy` Magento FE was printing the exception with given message.

Comment: Apologies I only saw your second comment. Without seeing your file structure it's hard to see why it's giving that error. Possibly open a new question and I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: the error reported may be due to there is no xml file in blank theme but that file will be in vendor folder on the root....I am still trying to figure out the solution for the same....

Comment: @BenCrook, I hope we no need to use any override directory there, as NAMESPACE\themename\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml is fine, In my case its worked.

Comment: @jafarpinjar Using that you are extending the XML not overriding it. If you are seeing the same results are overriding it's likely you are using the same block names.

Comment: @BenCrook, still i am not clear about it, so i am not added any override directory before, what is the main difference between using override directory and without that directory? even do we need to maintain same directory to override template files also?

Comment: Override will completely ignore the parent file, extend will merge your file with the parent file.