# magento 2.1.1 checkout page logo not display

Tags: magento2

I have set logo in header but it is showing in all pages except checkout page.Please tell how to set it.[image]

Comment: Somehow this is default practice now. I guess it has to do with removing clutter on the checkout pages.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: have you get solution?

Answer (score 7):

Override `checkout_index_index.xml` file and write below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" <!--here you can also use **layout="checkout"** -->xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

**NOTE:** in Magento 2.1 one extra layout is available for checkout `layout="checkout"`.

or if you want to remove extra `sign in link` from checkout page you can use below code in same file `checout_index_index.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" <!--here you can also use **layout="checkout"** -->xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
 </page>
```

after that, you can see checkout something like this.

[image]

Comment: where is located

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` you can override by using this path `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml`

Comment: override  means add folder for this path and  create file to checkout_i‌​ndex_index.xml

Comment: yes, if you are using `app/design` path otherwise you can override in your extension.

Comment: Hello i have add but it is showing in http://ourshop.in/migrate/checkout/cart/ link meas cart page but not dispay ni chechout page

Comment: check `layout="1column"` in your `<page>` tag?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: i have put your new code but error is gangrened 
There has been an error processing your request
Overriding view file '/home/ourshop/public_html/migrate/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/superstore/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml' does not match to any of the files.

Comment: use this path `app/design/frontend/Venus‌​theme/superstore/Mag‌​ento_Checkout/layout‌​/checkout_i‌​ndex_index.xml`

Comment: you can also look at this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107337/magento-2-checkout-index-xml-is-not-overriding

Comment: i have add file for your instruction but it not any effect app/design/frontend/Venus‌​theme/superstore/Mag‌​ento_Checko‌​ut/layout‌​/checkout‌​_i‌​ndex_index.xml

Comment: have you tried with my updated answer?

Comment: yes i have tried your ans first ans is working but in my  log is upper side display not  show in  i have sand screen short type please check by above screen short

Comment: have you used this `<move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>`? check proper this is correct i have personally checked.

Comment: yes but logo is show in upper side

Comment: so, what you want?

Comment: http://ourshop.in/migrate/checkout/ please check this link it not show in proper way

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148614/magento-2-1-1-checkout-page-logo-not-showing please check it.

Comment: or may be this problem is with this ves theme

Comment: have you get solution?

Answer (score 3):

Sometime it is a **generic or feel like a serious issue** like in luma theme or other magento theme(s), logo is appearing in checkout page but not in our custom theme.

So the actual problem is with our **customization in our custom theme**.

More detail :  If we see a **page layout file of checkout** that is `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml`

in that a statement is there that is  `<move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>`

and

> As we know the order of merging xml files are   **module(s) -> parent theme
>   -> current theme (custom theme)**.

so if any of our custom theme module (**global handler i.e. default** or checkout effected handler) **override the same move statement of logo** (with different destination) then **chances of logo not appear in checkout is 99%.**

> If logo appear after customization in checkout then **no issue**.

else **need to create a file if not exist** in your custom theme `app/design/frontend/[NAMESPACE]/[THEME]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

and add the line (copy the line from checkout page layout)  that is  `<move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>`

best place to added this move statement **before body close tag** to avoid override issue in same file :).