# magento 2.1.1 checkout page logo not showing

Tags: magento2

i have set logo in header but not show in proper way please tell how to set it.
i have change it code to:

[image]

Comment: magento 2.1.1 yes but my checkout  page logo not dispaly show i have add logo code in checkout_index_index.xml this file

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over again. You already asked that question. Use the edit feature to ask more information, creating the same question over again will most likely get you warned by a moderator and if you keep doing this you may end up being banned temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

Override checkout_index_index.xml file and write below code.

```
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
           <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
       </body>
    </page>
```

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout‌​_index_index.xml**

you can override by using this path `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout‌​/override/theme/Mage‌​nto/blank/checkout_i‌​ndex_index.xml`