# Magento 2 - Checkout Payment methods does not show

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme, payment-methods, frontend

I have a magento 2 site, with 2 different stores using different themes

```
1- Theme A
2- Theme B
```

**Theme B is the child of Theme A**

In the theme A checkout page, I have been able to display the payment methods, by using the **base override of** `checkout_index_index.xml` file . Before this, payment methods were not displayed

created a file

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\ThemeA\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\base\checkout_index_index.xml
```

with the following code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" />
</body>
```

This works fine and displays the payment methods properly

**For Theme B, I have tried the same approach but it does not work.**

I have checked the `JS`, and it returns me the proper object for the payment methods but they don't get displayed anywhere, it just shows the following message

> ```
> No payment method
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to display it

In the child theme, we have to override the parent theme files

so in Theme B, instead of

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\ThemeB\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\base\checkout_index_index.xml
```

It should be

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\ThemeB\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\ThemeA\checkout_index_index.xml
```

You can find a complete answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107473/47484)