# checkout_index_index.xml Breaking when overwriting

Tags: checkout, checkout-page

I'm trying to overwrite `checkout_index_index.xml` under `module-checkout`

It is currently using the file I have created in my theme but the shipping selection is breaking and now showing prices or reloading on zip code change.

**I have copied the whole file from the default theme** so it's not my code but maybe something isn't including like I found the discount item wasn't working.

So I had to add that manually but can't seem to find whats breaking the shipping any ideas thanks.

Path is

```
/theme_name/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste file path ?

Comment: @PawanKParmar Updated

Comment: it can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107473/44340

Comment: @PawanKParmar Not what I'm after sorry the file is overwriting fine and Magento is seeing it because I can add and remove things but the shipping methods are not showing correctly when I add the checkout_index_index.xml file to the layout folder with the same content as the default theme it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have not found the problem but I have found a solution

in checkout_index_index.xml in your theme, you can't copy all the content from the default theme but if you want to add stuff to the content section you can use

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
```

When using

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
```

The shipping table stops working

This is currently my way around it and you can then copy all the info inside

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.root" template="onepage.phtml" cacheable="false">
....
</block>
```

From the defult theme and chnage things as you wish i also recomend adding discount to the side bar when overwriting this file as it doenst seem to show the discount if you dont.

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
</item>
```